# Server calling client in real time (Xamarin Forms e Aspnet Core)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, websocket

I have an application (server) in AspNet Core C # that needs to notify a Xamarin Forms (client) application when there is an IP exchange on the server.
I currently use SignalR to make communication in real time. But when it changes the IP of the server this communication is lost.
At the moment I can not work with DNS name.
How can I resolve this issue?
Is it possible to do this with SignalR or should I look for some other component?

```cs
//Client Code
public static async Task SetupSignalR()
        {
            try
            {
                if (hubConnection == null || hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
                {
                    hubConnection = new HubConnection(Configuracao.ServerUrl + "");
                    var notificaoHub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificacaoHub");

                    var inicializar = App.Container.Get<IInicializacaoService>();                    

                    notificaoHub.On("NotificacaoTrocaIpServidor", NotificacaoTrocaIpServidor);

                    await hubConnection.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.RegistrarErro(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

//Server Code
public void ConfigurarIpServidor(DtoConfigurarIpServidorRequest dto)
        {

                IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificacaoHub>();
                context.Clients.All.NotificacaoTrocaIpServidor();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any example code ?

Comment: Follow the code

Comment: does the IP of the actual server the client is connected to change?

Comment: Yes, it changes from time to time

Comment: is the SignalR hub on that same server or a different server?

Comment: is on the server

Comment: I'm not sure how you possibly expect this to work?  The client is connected to a server IP.  The IP changes, so the connection will get broken.  You either need some mechanism to tell the client the IP has changed that IS NOT DEPENDENT TO THE SAME IP, or you need some sort of advanced network routing setup to handle this automatically.  You could probably use SignalR for this, but the SignalR hub needs to be on a different server (Azure hosted, maybe)